# read values of a column from file and print one bye one

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

My `xyz.csv` file has data as below:

```
**abc_hosts,def_host_id,sde_host_id,hostname,dffff_status,status,eeee,eeeeee,tttt,name1,name2,name3,**
start,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,2,3,eee,4,4,rrr,ggggg,323232,22323,2323232,sfdsfd,223333,443433323,45343,5445,213132,fdsfdfdfd,2332332321,3
end,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: are the IP address will always be on line which contains `eth0` on 4th field ?

Comment: ya Rahul, It will always be on line which contains eth0 on 4th field.               eth0:0,172.23.12.45
                       eth0:1,172.23.12.46
                       eth0:2,172.23.12.47

Comment: See comments on http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303498/135943 regarding vandalism vs. redacting sensitive information.

Comment: Please stop editing your question to make it into something else. If you have a new question, ask it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, IP address will always be in the line which will always contain `eth0`, depending on that you can run this command

```
grep eth0 Platform_Configuration.csv | cut -d',' -f5 | tr -d '**'
```

Comment: It's giving error as : tr: invalid option -- '\'

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested your code, but assuming you code is correct, here is a simple thing you can do.

```
echo  $(grep -A$i "start_interfaces_setup" Platform_Configuration.csv | cut -d ',' -f5) | tr " " "\n"
```

Watch the `tr` part in the last.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried tr part in the last and I am getting the out put as i wanted. but it's printing all values for three times. i want all IP should print once.

Answer (score 0):

Task can be done by single **sed**

```
sed -n '/.*eth0:[0-9]\+,/{s///;s/,/\n/;P;}' Platform_Configuration.csv
```

or

```
sed -n '/eth0/{s/,/\n/4g;D;};/\n/P' Platform_Configuration.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is delimited, I'd suggest something like

```
awk -F, '/eth0:[0-9]+/ {print $5}' Platform_Configuration.csv
```

or (more restrictively)

```
awk -F, '$4 ~ /eth0:[0-9]+/ {print $5}' Platform_Configuration.csv
```