# how to do string concatenation in bash script?

Tags: bash, text-processing

abc_hosts,pwd_host_id,pwd_host_id,hostname,ddd_status,dddd_status,

start_hosts,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,1,o1,fhffhfh,1,1,fff,fdfd,172.33.33.33,172.30.30.12,172.30.30.11,oreere.dff,43,443343,1111,43435,1099,43434443444,3232321312312
end_hosts,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: What line has the error?  Also, you have a space after `=` for `str4`

Comment: i am getting the error for below lines. "./Anitha.sh: line 19: str1: command not found

./Anitha.sh: line 21: str2: command not found

./Anitha.sh: line 23: str3: command not found
./Anitha.sh: line 24: str4: command not found"

Comment: shellcheck.net is really helpful; it points out that you've set arr1 but are using arr_t

Comment: You might want to pass this through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) it'll help clean up a bunch of errors along the way

Comment: @Sangram, when you edit a post to remove all details, the details are still viewable in the edit history.  If you are trying to prevent sensitive details from being publicly viewable, you shouldn't have posted them in the first place.  I have flagged this question for moderator attention.  Please don't vandalize your own posts.

Comment: @Wildcard , ya true but i have to do that. Sorry

Comment: @Sangram, my point is that you *can't*.  It doesn't prevent the prior versions of the question from being publicly viewable.  Not only that, but you need to **maintain the question** even if you take out the sensitive information.  Please read [this answer on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278716/307622) and then edit back *in* the CSV file, omitting *only* the sensitive information, so that the answers can still make sense for future readers.  Follow the steps in the linked answer to request redaction of the revision history.

Comment: The purpose of the stack exchange network is to build a repository of useful questions and answers *for the future*, **not** *just* to help the people asking right now.  Removing your question after you've gotten the help *you* needed is a poor way to "pay it forward" and poor thanks to the community that has helped you.  That said—redaction can be done.  Again, [see this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278716/307622).

Comment: @Wildcard ,I will do that for sure

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you really, really, *really* don't want to be doing this sort of thing in bash. There are tools that are specifically designed for this type of job and bash is very much not one of them. Attempting to do any but the most basic text parsing in bash is hard, error prone, and painful to read or write. It is also very slow.

Now, your specific error (please always include the *exact* error you are receiving) is:

```
/home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh: line 24:  : command not found
```

So the error is on line 24. Specifically, it is the space you have after the `=`:

```
str4= "$str1 $str3 $str2"
```

should be

```
str4="$str1 $str3 $str2"
```

You also have the same problem on line 25:

```
arr_t[$m]= $str4
```

should be

```
arr_t[$m]=$str4
```

I suggest you ask a different question, explain what your script is trying to do and we can give you a saner approach than `bash`ing your head against the wall like this.

Comment: Hi all can you check this link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303527/how-to-write-the-bash-script-dynamic-to-print-row-and-columns-data-and-update-th.  and can you please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: I changed the code now it's printing like this :   1
   1
   eth0:0
   172.16.5.45
   255.255.255.0
   172.16.5.1
   1
   1
 1   2
   1   1
   eth0:0   eth0:1
   172.16.5.45   172.16.5.46
   255.255.255.0   255.255.255.0
   172.16.5.1   172.16.5.1
   1   1
   1   1
1   2   3
   1   1   1
   eth0:0   eth0:1   eth0:2
   172.16.5.45   172.16.5.46   172.16.5.47
   255.255.255.0   255.255.255.0   255.255.255.0
   172.16.5.1   172.16.5.1   172.16.5.1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
How to print all in once?

Comment: Dat bash pun though