# How to write the bash script dynamic to print row and columns data and update the same data in the same file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, array, csv

abc_hosts,pwd_host_id,pwd_host_id,hostname,ddd_status,dddd_status,

start_hosts,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,1,o1,fhffhfh,1,1,fff,fdfd,172.33.33.33,172.30.30.12,172.30.30.11,oreere.dff,43,443343,1111,43435,1099,43434443444,3232321312312
end_hosts,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
abc_hosts,pwd_host_id,pwd_host_id,hostname,ddd_status,dddd_status,

start_hosts2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,1,o1,fhffhfh,1,1,fff,fdfd,172.33.33.33,172.30.30.12,172.30.30.11,oreere.dff,43,443343,1111,43435,1099,43434443444,3232321312312
end_hosts2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Where does this data come from?  CSV seems to be a really bad choice, maybe you can get the same data in a different format?

Comment: Ya Sato, but i don't have other choice . i have do it in with csv format . can you guide me on this.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764454/transpose-csv-data-with-awk-pivot-transformation

Comment: @Sangram, **please stop vandalizing your own posts.**  What are you trying to solve by doing so?

Comment: See comments on http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303498/135943 regarding vandalism vs. redacting sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` script should get you started:

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }
$1 {
    if ($1 == "end_" tablename) {
        exit 0;
    } else if ($1 == "start_" tablename) {
        in_table = 1;
    } else if ($1 == tablename) {
        count = split($0, columns);
    }
    next;
}

in_table {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        values[i] = values[i] "," $i;
    }
}

END {
    for (i = 2; i <= count; i++) {
        if (columns[i]) {
            print columns[i] " - " substr(values[i], 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -f config.awk -v tablename=interfaces_setup config.csv
```

Comment: superb Michael, Thank you so much. i like "awk" .